# Website is not allowing to make selection on radio or checkbox buttons using selenium chrome driver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using **chrome driver** as the **web driver for selenium based automation**, till today I was able to make a selection on the website from which I am **scraping** the data but now the website is not allowing me to make these selections in chrome driver.

However, if I am making the same selection in the chrome browser, the website is allowing me to do it.

Here's the code that I am using to make the selections:

```
browser.execute_script("$('#" + radioButtonTickID + "').click()")
```

OR

```
radioSelect = WebDriverWait(browser,60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((
By.ID,radioButtonTickID)))
radioSelect.click()
```

Can anybody suggest what will be the reason behind this?

Comment: Without providing your code and what error you see in the console etc it will be very hard to determine where the issue is. Can you please provide a few details of what you have tried and what issues you faced

Comment: @Vin - I am not getting any error. Though, I have added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Can you try with the id directly instead of parameterizing and see if that works? also, I don't see ; after the click(). Have you looked into this site for more examples of how to execute_script? https://dzone.com/articles/perform-actions-using-javascript-in-python-seleniu.

Comment: try like this. browser.execute_script("$('#' + radioButtonTickID).click();"). there is nothing after the radiobuttonTickID so I don't see any need of using + ". Also after #you have provided " just replace with '